# Commit objects to state in vuex

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm trying to get objects from axios response via `$store.commit('fetchFunction', response.data)`. I need to `computed` out in App.vue (root component) to store the array "globally" in SPA (`vue-router`).
This is what I got.

### auth.js

```
axios.get('/api/to/userController/id')
    .then(response => {

    //this is a nice json
    console.log(response.data.data);
    app.$store.commit('userProfile', response.data.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {

    console.log(error);
    });
```

### store.js

```
state: {
    userProfile: {}
},
mutations: {
    userProfile (state, payload) {
        state.userProfile = payload;
    }
},
getters: {
    userProfile: state => {

    //this is [__ob__: Observer] lenght: 0
    console.log(state.userProfile)}
    return state.userProfile;
}
```

### App.vue

```
created() {

    //this is filled with the observer from store.js - Until reload page!
    //after reload page - it is null!
    console.log();
},
computed: {

    userProfile() {
        return this.$store.getters.UserProfile;
    }
}
```

My actual problem is that the object is goning to be an observer and `store` doesnt store it, if i change the routes or reload the page.
I have almost the same funtion before, just with `true` and `false` (I handle the status of auth with a `JWT Token`) and it works like a charme.
My problem is to pass the object in a nice way.

Comment: Use sessionstorage

Comment: Nice solution! That's a way I like and it work's really fine! thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to track changes through route change.